# re-center div when content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is centered on the middle of the screen. I need to pass some text to the div and the text will be of various lengths. The problem is that when I pass text to the div, it changes size but wont stay centered. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/h0d097vp/) that demonstrates the problem.

I currently center the div like this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
#divError{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h0d097vp/3/

Comment: I always forget about `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`

Comment: think of like this: point of transform of a div if top left, not center, as usually it's in programs like photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Your div is not centered. The existing positioning centered the top left corner of the div.

Try this:

```
#divError{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
             transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h0d097vp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set constant width?, if so here's your answer [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/h0d097vp/7/%20%22JSFiddler)

Just added

```
width: 100px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div is not centered in the beginning either. left: 50% means that the diff starts at 50%, which means that the start of the div is at the center of the page.
When the div has a width of 200px, than still only the start will be at the center.
You can give the div a fixed width, and than add a negative margin of half the width so the div will really be in the center of the page.

Like

```
#divError{
     width: 200px;
     margin-left: -100px;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `top` and `left` they position whichever side they are named directly at the position given.  So `left: 50%` will always have the leftmost side positioned directly at the 50% mark.  This is not the center, but starts the left side of the div at the center.  The same occurs with `top: 50%`.  In order to use `top` and `left` you'd need to know the overall width and height and subtract half of their value from their respective `top` and `left` (e.g left: calc(50% - ([width of element] / 2)).  Since you are using dynamic content you can't know either the height or the width (unless you make them static.)

So what can you do?  There are a few ways, but my favorite at the moment is fairly new.  It's called flexbox.  It's [support is decent](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).  There's a [nice snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from css-tricks as well.

The relevant code to center an element both vertically and horizontally would go like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {
    $.get("http://lorem.mannfolio.com/", function(data) {
      var lorem = data.split("\n\n");
      $(".centered").html(lorem[0]);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Change text</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">I'm centered No matter what you put in me.</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```